# How to receive Data from a stream in iOS (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, stream, alamofire

I am trying to get data from a stream in swift. I know how to handle this in Android, but I dont know what to do in iOS.
In Android I do the following to read data from my server an save it as file to my device:

```
URL url = new URL(uri);
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

connection.connect();

input = connection.getInputStream();
output = new FileOutputStream(context.getFileStreamPath(filename));

byte data[] = new byte[1024];
int count;
while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
    output.write(data, 0, count);
}

File file = context.getFileStreamPath(filename);
```

How can I do the same with swift? I am using Alamofire for other requests.

best regards

Comment: Did you ever solve this?  I am working on something that involves the same type of situation.

Comment: Long time ago, but I am sure alomofire solves it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almofire provides methods to download streams directly. This is an example mentioned in the Almofire github page

```
let destination = Alamofire.Request.suggestedDownloadDestination(directory: .DocumentDirectory, domain: .UserDomainMask)
Alamofire.download(.GET, "https://httpbin.org/stream/100", destination: destination)
```

Comment: but how to specify chunk size using alamofire?